# XCode 4.2 and dealloc obsolete

Tags: objective-c

I started to use Xcode 4.2 and it seems you can't use anymore dealloc and release like you were doing before.
If I write the following implementation:

```
@implementation Person

@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;

- (void) dealloc
{
    [firstName release];
    [lastName release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The compiler bothers me saying that release is unavailable in automatic reference counting mode. Is it a feature of Objective-C 2.0? Where I can read more about it?

Comment: Yes, it's a new feature of Obj-C 2.0, introduced in Xcode 4.

Comment: Clarification: Obj-C 2.0 was out long before ARC, and ARC is a feature of the LLVM3 compiler that shipped with Xcode 4.2. It is not available in Xcode 4.0 or 4.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a feature of [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#introducing-automatic-reference-counting) (ARC). If you turn ARC off, you can use manual memory management, or (Mac OS X only) garbage collection.

Comment: Sounds as if ARC is a feature of itself :P

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will have a look at ARC at this point.

Answer (score 3):

In ARC you don't need to use release or autorelease, the compiler does it all for you. A quick search on the Apple developer site found the [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html).

Comment: Before he comes back saying his CF code is leaking: you can't use `retain`, `release`, or `autorelease` for Cocoa objects. You still need to use memory management functions for CoreFoundation objects, and there are macros that need to be used when casting to/from Cocoa/CoreFoundation so that the compiler knows whether or not it is responible for managing the memory of these casted objects.

Answer (score 0):

What about when using library code that needs to be compatible with both ARC and non ARC?
Are we forced to write two versions of the same code where the only difference is a removed dealloc method?